# Boostrap 3 span issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where I am trying to place different div's on the same line without much luck using Bootstrap 3. I'm trying to place `<div id="score">` on the same line as `<div id="info">` but one pulled left and the other pulled right. Can anyone show me how to do this? I've made a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jsykes/8hjhpnLc/2/) Thanks

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <small>Posted by: John</small>
    <span class="pull-right">

<small>10-Dec-2016</small>

<!----Place bottom two DIV's on same line, one pulled left and the other pulled right--->
<div id="info">more info</div>
<div id="score">Score - 10</div>
</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use nested bootstrap's row/cols to add sub cols in a col. https://jsfiddle.net/8hjhpnLc/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/CBCcfiYbDW)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <small>Posted by: John</small>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <small>10-Dec-2016</small>
        </div>
    </div>
<!----Place bottom two DIV's on same line, one pulled left and the other pulled right--->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="info">more info</div>
        </div>
        <div id="score" class="col-md-6">Score - 10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```